# how to implement the goal difference calculation to achieve a tiebreaker?

Tags: javascript

I work with the following data set

```
const data = [
  {
    team: {
      id: "1018",
      title: "Team 1",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-1/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-1.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 1,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 3,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 1,
    points: 4,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "211",
      title: "Team 2",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-2/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-2.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 1,
    goals_for: 1,
    goals_against: 3,
    free_play_score: 1,
    points: 1,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "2098",
      title: "Team 3",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-3/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-3.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 0,
    goals_against: 0,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 0,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "196",
      title: "Team 4",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-4/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-4.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 1,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 1,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "250",
      title: "Team 5",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-5/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-5.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 2,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 4,
    goals_against: 3,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 2,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "147",
      title: "Team 6",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-6/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-5.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 2,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 5,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 2,
  },
];
```

I need to sort them by points, so that I can later print standings

```
data.sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points);
```

But then I get two tie scenarios, between the teams that have two points and those that have one point, I must here use [Goal difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal_difference) to order them,

Goal difference consists of

> Goal difference (or points difference) is calculated as the number of
> goals (or points) scored in all league matches minus the number of
> goals or points conceded

In my case, first I thought about obtaining the difference goals of each team, for this I try the following

```
const clone = data.concat().map((entry) => ({
  ...entry,
  team: { ...entry.team },
  goal_difference: entry.goals_for - entry.goals_against,
}));
```

The `goal_difference` property is added to each team, but from now on I don't know how to proceed, to achieve the positions of teams that do not have a tie are ordered and respected. I appreciate your suggestions

** Update 0 **

The expected output should be

```
const data = [
  {
    team: {
      id: "1018",
      title: "Team 1",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-1/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-1.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 1,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 3,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 1,
    points: 4,
    goal_difference: 2,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "147",
      title: "Team 6",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-6/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-5.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 2,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 5,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 2,
    goal_difference: 4,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "250",
      title: "Team 5",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-5/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-5.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 2,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 4,
    goals_against: 3,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 2,
    goal_difference: 1,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "196",
      title: "Team 4",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-4/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-4.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 1,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 1,
    goal_difference: 0,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "211",
      title: "Team 2",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-2/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-2.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 1,
    goals_for: 1,
    goals_against: 3,
    free_play_score: 1,
    points: 1,
    goal_difference: -2,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "2098",
      title: "Team 3",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-3/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-3.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 0,
    goals_against: 0,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 0,
    goal_difference: 0,
  },
];
```

Comment: You need to expand your sort callback to include your goal difference. `const pointsDiff = b.points - a.points; if (pointsDiff === 0) {// Check goal difference here} return pointsDiff;`

Comment: good idea, testing

Comment: In expected output there is team with 2 points but there isn't in input data.

Comment: I check what you comment, fixed!

Comment: Charles, it worked as you suggested, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to detect when points are equal and then sort on goal difference instead.  You can do this inline without adding to the object, if you prefer:

```
data.sort((a, b) => b.points == a.points ? 
(b.goals_for - b.goals_against) - (a.goals_for - b.goals_against) : 
b.points - a.points );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first `map` over you data to add `goals_difference` property to each object and then use `sort` method to first sort by points and then by goals difference if the points are equal.

```js
const data = [{"team":{"id":"1018","title":"Team 1","permalink":"http://localhost/app/teams/team-1/","logo":"http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-1.png"},"games_played":1,"won_games":1,"tide_games":0,"lost_games":0,"goals_for":3,"goals_against":1,"free_play_score":1,"points":4},{"team":{"id":"211","title":"Team 2","permalink":"http://localhost/app/teams/team-2/","logo":"http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-2.png"},"games_played":2,"won_games":0,"tide_games":1,"lost_games":1,"goals_for":1,"goals_against":3,"free_play_score":1,"points":1},{"team":{"id":"2098","title":"Team 3","permalink":"http://localhost/app/teams/team-3/","logo":"http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-3.png"},"games_played":1,"won_games":0,"tide_games":1,"lost_games":0,"goals_for":0,"goals_against":0,"free_play_score":0,"points":0},{"team":{"id":"196","title":"Team 4","permalink":"http://localhost/app/teams/team-4/","logo":"http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-4.png"},"games_played":1,"won_games":0,"tide_games":1,"lost_games":0,"goals_for":1,"goals_against":1,"free_play_score":0,"points":1},{"team":{"id":"250","title":"Team 5","permalink":"http://localhost/app/teams/team-5/","logo":"http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-5.png"},"games_played":2,"won_games":2,"tide_games":0,"lost_games":0,"goals_for":4,"goals_against":3,"free_play_score":0,"points":2},{"team":{"id":"147","title":"Team 6","permalink":"http://localhost/app/teams/team-6/","logo":"http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-5.png"},"games_played":2,"won_games":2,"tide_games":0,"lost_games":0,"goals_for":5,"goals_against":1,"free_play_score":0,"points":2}]

const result = data
  .map(({ goals_for: gf, goals_against: ga, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, goal_difference: gf - ga}))
  .sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points || b.goal_difference - a.goal_difference)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
const data = [
  {
    team: {
      id: "1018",
      title: "Team 1",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-1/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-1.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 1,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 3,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 1,
    points: 4,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "211",
      title: "Team 2",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-2/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-2.png",
    },
    games_played: 2,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 1,
    goals_for: 1,
    goals_against: 3,
    free_play_score: 1,
    points: 1,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "2098",
      title: "Team 3",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-3/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-3.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 0,
    goals_against: 0,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 0,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "196",
      title: "Team 4",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-4/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-4.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 0,
    tide_games: 1,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 1,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 1,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "250",
      title: "Team 5",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-5/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/team-5.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 1,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 4,
    goals_against: 3,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 1,
  },
  {
    team: {
      id: "147",
      title: "Team 6",
      permalink: "http://localhost/app/teams/team-6/",
      logo: "http://localhost/app/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/team-5.png",
    },
    games_played: 1,
    won_games: 1,
    tide_games: 0,
    lost_games: 0,
    goals_for: 5,
    goals_against: 1,
    free_play_score: 0,
    points: 1,
  },
];


function sortArray(a, b) {
    var aPoints = a.points;
    var bPoints = b.points;
  var aDifference = a.goals_for - a.goals_against;
  var bDifference = b.goals_for - b.goals_against;
  
    var r;
  if (aPoints < bPoints) {
    r = 1;
  } else if (aPoints > bPoints) {
    r = -1;
  } else {
    if (aDifference < bDifference) {
      r = 1;
    } else if (aDifference > bDifference) {
      r = -1;
    } else {
      r = 0;
    }
  }
    return r;
}


data.sort(sortArray);

console.log(data);
```

This is a custom sort that does a normal descending sort (ie, team with most points is first) except that, where the points match, it then checks the goal differences and sorts on that as well